# Absolute z-index issue in IE when expand hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with position of a block (div). I am newbie in CSS, please help me.

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/9rEmt/ (please take a look there) to view online in IE.

If I put `absoulte` at positioning, the issue appears: (please choose Compatibility mode if you have newer version of IE )

[image]

instead of (without compatibility mode, just simply in IE9) :

[image]

Where is the problem ? How to solve this issue ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Curious side note: if you check a box and then uncheck it will display properly. Perhaps a problem going from display: hidden to display: block in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE to position an element relative to another element the parent element needs to e positioned itself.

Try to add this to your stylesheet:

```
#item { 
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Also, move the `items` div into the `item` div so that `items` is able to be positioned relative to `item`.

http://jsfiddle.net/U92jm/

Comment: Have you test what you wrote above ? Won't work. I have to `relative` the #items not #item. #items is hidden and it must be positioned under `Select` text. Moreover, If I click the box then the hidden elements become visible and the below text will be moved downside.

Comment: I thought you had to `absolute` #items. If so you can't absolute something within a containing div if that containing div isn't positioned. That is why you would place #items with #item, relative position #item, then the absolute positioning of #items will take effect within the #item div.

Comment: Here is what I was thinking:  http://jsfiddle.net/U92jm/ You will obviously have to adjust your styles to get it looking the way you want.